# take out objects from randomizer obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random, nsarray

I'm a new "developer" trying to build some iPhone app
I'm making an app which gets text from a list of objects in a NSArray and then randomizes them and display one in a TextView, here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)azione{
NSArray *myArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Pasta",@"Pizza",@"Wait",@"Go", nil]; 
int length = [myArray count];
int chosen = arc4random() % length;
testo.text = [myArray objectAtIndex: chosen];
```

}

what I want to do now, is when I open the app and get a random object, to take it out from the list, so that it won't be picked again

ex. I open the app>I get "Pizza">Do the action again>I don't get "Pizza" anymore, only "Pasta" "Wait" and "Go"

What should I do ? Which code should I use ?

Thanks for answers

Comment: What if all 4 objects are removed?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the end of your function.

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex: chosen]
```

Comment: That's an NSArray not an NSMutableArray.

Comment: I changed it as an NSMutableArray and I coded like this:

- (IBAction)azione{
    NSMutableArray *myArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Pasta",@"Pizza",@"Wait",@"Go", nil]; 
 int length = [myArray count];
 int chosen = arc4random() % length;
 testo.text = [myArray objectAtIndex: chosen];
 [myArray removeObjectAtIndex: chosen];
}

but nothing is happening, as I open the app, get an object and that continues to appear

what should I do ?
Thanks

Comment: @Kenny: Thanks, I missed that. @David, is the action getting called more than once?

Comment: It doesn't remember that you've removed an item because you're recreating the array on each call to that function. (D'oh!)  You may have to create the array in -init and store it in an instance variable.

Comment: You're right, I'm trying hard to do something but it doesn't happen anything, could you give me a code sample please ?

Thanks